# Limit Salesforce objects and fields in Tableau Desktop

Tags: tableau

In connecting Salesforce to Tableau Desktop it brings in every single object as a table. Within each table/object it brings in every single field. The issue is there are many standard objects my org doesn't use. Within each object there are even more fields which we don't need.

Is there a way when connecting Salesforce to Tableau Desktop to do data analysis to only show certain objects/tables, and within those, pick which fields to display.

My hope is to have a setup for all the analysts on my team to just open up Tableau Desktop, connect to our Salesforce instance, and just see the tables (and fields within those tables) that are relevant for analysis and not every single object and field.

Answer (score 0):

When you say your "team," that must mean that you have either Tableau Online (now called Tableau Cloud) or Tableau Server.  If you have Tableau Desktop, that came with Tableau Prep.  What you need to do is pull it all into Tableau Prep, get rid of all the columns that aren't needed, and output to a published data source on either Tableau Online or Tableau Server.  I've done this myself, and I understand how even though Tableau can literally process billions of rows instantaneously, additional columns/fields can slow things down and I too would dread distributing tons of fields to people who won't use them correctly.  The site/server admin can publish the source so that you know that business-but-not-math minded people really can't mess up what their trying to visualize.